# solvable group, commutator, algebraic closure, extensions fields, ....

Tags: abstract-algebra

There are 2 questions

> 1. If a group $G$ is solvable and $C$ is the commutator of subgroup of $G$, then $C\neq G$.

I probably think it should be used the theorem as : $G/N$ is abelian group iff $C\subseteq N$.

Let {$H_i$} be a composition series of group $G$ and $H_{i+1}/H_i$ be an abelian group. So, $H_n$ contains the commutator $C$ of $G$ for $G=H_n$. I do not know the next process.

> 2. Let $\mathbb{F}$ be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and let $\alpha ,\beta \in \mathbb{F} $ be zeroes of $ x^3-x+1 $ and of  $x^3-2x^2+2$, respectively. Show $\mathbb{Z}_3(\alpha)=\mathbb{Z}_3(\beta)$.

I do not know where to start..

Comment: I think you should ask two separate questions for $1$. and $2$. because they are completely unrelated.

Comment: Yes, this would be better, although both have been answered already on MSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) A group is solvable if and only if the derived series ends with the trivial group, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvable_group). But if $G=[G,G]$, and $G$ is non-trivial, its derived series cannot end with the trivial group. Hence for a solvable, non-trivial group $G$ we have $G\neq [G,G]$.

2.) Note: the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is the
union
$$
\overline{\mathbb{F}_{p}}=\bigcup_{k\ge 1} \mathbb{F}_{p^k}.
$$
For $p=3$ we obtain the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_3=\mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: Sorry,Can you explain a definition of dervied series?

Comment: In the wikipedia article above, click on "derived series" in the third line.